# Why does cargo use a specific dependency version?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

When trying to follow the instructions of the [pathfinder](https://github.com/servo/pathfinder.git) library, i.e:

```
cd demo/native
cargo run --release
```

I get errors due to the compilation of the dependency `winit` version 0.19.3:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/yairchu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/winit-0.19.3/src/platform/macos/view.rs:209:9
    |
205 | extern fn has_marked_text(this: &Object, _sel: Sel) -> BOOL {
    |                                                        ---- expected `bool` because of return type
...
209 |         (marked_text.length() > 0) as i8
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `bool`, found `i8`
```

If I try changing the version used to the latest (which works fine for me) by changing `Cargo.toml`:

```
--- a/demo/native/Cargo.toml
+++ b/demo/native/Cargo.toml
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@ rev = "f3df871ac8c3926fe9106d86a3e51e20aa50d3cc"

 [dependencies.winit]
-version = "<0.19.4" # 0.19.4 causes build errors https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/pull/1105
+version = "0.27.2"
```

I still get the same errors!

Interestingly, I notice this in cargo's output:

```
   Compiling winit v0.19.3
   Compiling winit v0.27.2
```

It appears to now be building both the version I specified and the old version.

I'm lost. Also using `--verbose` didn't help elucidate why cargo chooses to build this specific dependency.

- Is it using two versions of the same library in one executable?
- How can I find out why cargo chooses to build this library? (so that I can update it to the working version)

Thanks! Rust noob

Comment: The other package is probably indirectly required by another package

Comment: @mousetail do we have any way of finding out by which package it is required?

Comment: @yairchu `cargo tree`, specifically `-d` which lists all the duplicate packages (with different versions) at the top, then shows a tree of their dependents.

Comment: @Masklinn that's very helpful! `cargo tree` shows that the library is used by another dependency, "surfman". So is my understanding correct that multiple versions of the library can be used at the same time?

Comment: @Masklinn would you turn this into an answer so I may accept it?

Comment: "So is my understanding correct that multiple versions of the library can be used at the same time?" yes, as long as the two do not interact it should be fine. Since 1.31 through the renaming feature you can actually depend on the same crate multiple times, using different versions. This can be useful if e.g. you want to use one version of the dependency, but one of your own dependencies uses types from an other version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How can I find out why cargo chooses to build this library?

`cargo tree` elaborates on whose dependency is each sub-dependency.

### Is it using two versions of the same library in one executable?

It is.

You can depend on different versions of the the same crate. This can be useful if you want to use one version of the dependency, but one of your own dependencies uses another version.

<sub>(thanks @Masklinn for the answers in the comments!)</sub>